# How to move focus to another "tab group" in Intellij IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine, pycharm

IDEs based on the IntelliJ platform let you split the editor in various ways, but I don't see an option to move focus from one editor to another using just keyboard (something like `other-window` from Emacs).

Is there an "action" to do that?

Comment: To be sure we use the same words: the "editor" gathers all the tabs in all the groups. We don't want to move from an editor to another, we want to move to another tab group, groups being created when splitting the editor.

Answer (score 48):

For mac users, the default shortcut is <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 37):

I think you're already find answer, but for someone who have same question and find this post like me.
Go to **Prefernces -> Keymap** or simple use search in preference and find **Goto Next Splitter** and make your own hotkey for this action.

Comment: This only works if the tab group is in the same window. It doesn't move to the next tab group which exists in its own window.

Answer (score 6):

Main Menu Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab

There's also Switcher (Ctrl+Tab) available in the same menu as Goto Next/Previous Splitter which switches between splitted editor parts, tool windows, and many other things.

Comment: I remap ctrl+tab and ctrl+shift+tab to switch between tabs so it acts like, amongst other things, chrome. I find the switcher a little less useful than I probably should.... :/

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> works for Windows system.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS it is <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> keys to switch between tab groups