# PyCharm switch between windows with split screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In PyCharm, what is the keyboard shortcut (or menu command so I can define my own shortcut) to switch between windows in split screen?

To rephrase, when I can see two files on the screen, one in the left pane and the other in the right, how do I move the cursor from the left pane to the right pane without using the mouse?

In emacs, this would be "c-x o", but PyCharm interprets that as switching between tabs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move focus to another "tab group" in Intellij IDEs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611033/how-to-move-focus-to-another-tab-group-in-intellij-ides)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the possible duplicate answers my question. I haven't used PyCharm in a while...

Comment: It does. What that OP is calling "tab group" is the same you do with left and right pane. PyCharm is based on the IntelliJ platform, so the answers you see there are valid for PyCharm. I had the same doubt as you, and those answers (top 2) worked for me (I'm running PyCharm 5, but it looks like those solutions have been working for a long time).

Answer (score 24):

in (**pycharm version 3.4**)

```
CTRL + TAB
```

key will show a window.

you can switch by using this **window** to other **splited**  windows of pycharm.

Even, you can switch to  **project toolbox** elements.

[for shortcut configuration visit this site.](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

have fun with pycharm...

Comment: Doesn't work if the same file is opened on both sides :(

Answer (score 17):

PyCharm 2018.1 (MacOS Highe Sierra)

```
Option + Tab
```

Answer (score 12):

This option is called `Goto Next Splitter` in Pycharm. In version `2018.3` (MacOS Mojave) the shortcut is `Option + Tab`, but you can edit it easily:

> Preferences `(cmd + ,)` -> Keymap -> Goto Next Splitter.

Answer (score 6):

In Linux it can be achieved through the main menu:

```
Window -> Editor Tabs -> Goto Next Splitter
```

Unfortunately, there is no predefined shortcut for this operation. However, you can create your custom shortcut easy:

```
Settings -> Keymap
```

Comment: Thank you man, this answer made my life a lot better! FYI, the shortcut on macOS is alt+tab (or option+tab)

Answer (score 3):

For those familiar with vim
there is the IdeaVim extension for pycharm

and you can use vim key mapping:

for splitting a window:

```
ctrl + w + n     # horizontally
ctrl + w + v     # verically
```

for switching between splitted windows:

```
ctrl + w + [arrow]
ctrl-w + w
ctrl-w + W
```

switching by a number:

```
[number] + ctrl-w + w
```

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm 3.4 (Windows)

```
CTRL + TAB
```

Comment: this doesn't explicitly switch between tabs, but rather recent files. So it may or may not work, depending on your workflow